# Close http2 client connection after every request

Tags: go, client, http2

I want to close http2 client connection after every request (like disabling keep-alive connection in http1.1). I tried adding header `Connection: close` but that gives 
*http2: client conn not usable* error.

I tried using request.Close = true as well as specified in the document, but still getting error.

Following is the code snippet which I am using:

```
func main() {

    enableCompression := false

    transport2 := &http2.Transport{
        DisableCompression: !enableCompression,
        AllowHTTP:          true,
        DialTLS: func(network, addr string, cfg *tls.Config) (net.Conn, error) {
            return net.Dial(network, addr)
        },
    }

    // Create http client
    client := http.Client{
        Transport: transport2,
        Timeout:   time.Duration(1 * time.Second),
    }

    var err error
    var request *http.Request
    if request, err = createRequest(); err == nil {
        request.Close = true
        var response *http.Response

        if response, err = client.Do(request); err == nil {
            fmt.Println(response)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("error: ", err)
        }
    }
}

func createRequest() (request *http.Request, err error) {
    if request, err = http.NewRequest("GET", "http://0.0.0.0:1010/hello/sayHello", nil); err == nil {
        fmt.Println(request)
    }
    return
}
```

This gives error:
*http2: client conn not usable (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)*

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm thinking to reuse this question for generic "golang: I want to control HTTP/2 connection".

Answer (score 0):

HTTP/2 does not allow that behavior.

https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#rfc.section.8.1.2

> 8.1.2.2. Connection-Specific Header Fields
>
> HTTP/2 does not use the Connection header field to indicate
>   connection-specific header fields; in this protocol,
>   connection-specific metadata is conveyed by other means. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> This means that an intermediary transforming an HTTP/1.x message to
>   HTTP/2 will need to remove any header fields nominated by the
>   Connection header field, along with the Connection header field
>   itself. Such intermediaries SHOULD also remove other
>   connection-specific header fields, such as Keep-Alive,
>   Proxy-Connection, Transfer-Encoding, and Upgrade, even if they are not
>   nominated by the Connection header field.

see also

- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22441
- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17717

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Just curious, if I want to close the connection after every request for HTTP/2, what can be done? Go wouldn't allow that at all?

Comment: you can try https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/http2/transport.go#L475 but really http/2 is different from http/1.1. what you ask somehow defeats its purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this seems to work. Agreed, that this would defeat the purpose but adding Header <Connection:close> in http2 server handler does do the work, so I think it should have worked for client as well. Ref: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20977

Comment: I see, thanks for the link. Note that it tears down the connection when it become idle, check the comment https://github.com/golang/net/commit/97aa3a539ec716117a9d15a4659a911f50d13c3c#diff-51f54e5e768ac5a5b2539aebaf738475R2350 I am unsure about the conditions to consider the connection as idle, but as a quick guess, it might not be immediate.